# Why does str.removesuffix and str.removeprefix want to make a copy

Tags: python, string

Looking at [`str.removeprefix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) and [`str.removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#str.removeprefix) it says:

> If the string starts/ends with the prefix/suffix string ... Otherwise, **return a copy** of the original string

And the specification in PEP shows a Python equivalent code with returning copy in the `else:`, not returning just existing ref:

```
def removeprefix(self: str, prefix: str, /) -> str:
    if self.startswith(prefix):
        return self[len(prefix):]
    else:
        return self[:]

def removesuffix(self: str, suffix: str, /) -> str:
    # suffix='' should not call self[:-0].
    if suffix and self.endswith(suffix):
        return self[:-len(suffix)]
    else:
        return self[:]
```

My question is what's the point of making a copy `self[:]` anyway? Since strings are immutable, wouldn't it be more efficient just to return the original?

Comment: Probably under the assumption that the calling code is likely expecting a new string to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually make a copy, unless the original string was an instance of a `str` subclass. The person who wrote the change probably just picked bad wording. Ideally, the docs wouldn't imply anything about the identity of the return value in the no-match case.

You can check the lack of copy with a current Python 3.9 alpha build, or by [reading the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.0a6/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L12792).

Note that the bytearray version of this method *does* return a copy in the no-match case, because bytearrays are mutable.

Comment: There's some discussion about the wording [here](https://mail.python.org/archives/list/python-dev@python.org/thread/WFEWPAOVXOGY7UDXSKMYLVWBCFSHI3VT/) (search for 'copy').

And [this github comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/18939#pullrequestreview-378633200) says '"return the original" is an implementation detail' meaning they decided mentioning that was not helpful.

Comment: @AlexHall: It's definitely an implementation detail, but "return a copy" also sounds like it's specifying an implementation detail. Ideally, the wording wouldn't imply anything one way or another.

Comment: I don't understand - if the docs say it returns a copy then it must return a copy, no? The implementation can't then go and return the identical object as an optimization or implementation detail.  (bytearray obviously has to return a copy)